# Error: Cannot find module 'three' from

Tags: typescript, three.js, gulp

I have TypeScript 2.3.2. I use gulp.

I installed Three.js like this:

```
npm install @types/three --save-dev
```

When I write command `gulp` I see the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'three' from
'E:\_Projects\8observer8.bitbucket.io\ThreeJS\BattleCity3D\src'
```

Screenshots: https://yadi.sk/d/wDK1SZ6U3HkCzu

Comment: It is work when I comment this line: import * as THREE from "three"; and replace it by /// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/three/index.d.ts" /> Why?

Comment: Do not edit the title when solved, write an answer to your own question instead.

Comment: Also, avoid screenshots of code. Put the relevant code in the question itself as preformatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I replaced this line:

```
// this line does't work. Error: Cannot find module 'three' from ...
import * as THREE from "three";
```

By this:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/three/index.d.ts" />
```